# How to subset data frame that has " in it?

Tags: r, subset

I have a dataframe where one of the column is the following characters:

df$value is the following characters 23, 34', 45'67"

I am not sure how I can subset my data so that I pick all characters that has " in them.

I did the following:

```
p='"'
df2 <- subset(df1, grepl(p, df1$values) )
```

But i guess that problem is in actual " character, cause it wont subset me the  row with 45'67"

Comment: Maybe escape the character? `\"`